# ruby 1.9 -- Gem is there but it says its not?

Tags: ruby, macos

I just installed 1.9 on my 10.6 OSX, and it runs as the "ruby1.9" command.

So I'm trying to do:

```
sudo rake1.9 install
```

But it keeps telling me

```
Jeweler (or a dependency) not available. Install it with: gem install jeweler
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- git
```

However, if I type:

```
gem1.9 list
```

The jeweler gem is clear as day right there... wtf!?! Why is it like this...? Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's saying the `git` gem/library/file isn't found:

```
no such file to load -- git
```